# WCF Service Host does not come up after F5

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF 4 Service project.  I press F5 but it just takes me to `http://localhost` and shows the file directory.  Not sure why it's not running the WCF Service Host.  I have my WCF service project set as the startup project.

```
  <!-- SOAP Binding -->
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="soapBinding">
        <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <!-- Enable RESTful Endpoints-->
  <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webBinding"></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

This DOES create a WSDL if I were to add it to another C# project for example and add via service reference.  That's why I can't see why the test client would not show anything after I specified the same url (the one I just added to a C# project which DID create a wsdl so I know it works) the test client says added after I click OK but shows absolutely nothing in the test client UI right after it says it added it successfully.  I tried on another dev machine, he gets the same deal with my service.

UPDATED - More info from my side on setup:

**Web.config in our WCF Service project**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="Events.svc" service="OurCompany.API.OurService"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>

      <!-- SOAP Binding -->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="soapBinding">
            <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <!-- Enable RESTful Endpoints-->
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webBinding"></binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>


    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>

        <!-- allow XML REST -->
        <behavior name="poxBehavior">
            <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <!--<behavior name="jsonBehavior"><enableWebScript/></behavior>-->
        <!-- allow JSON REST -->
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>


    <services>

      <service name="EventInventory.API.Events" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
          <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
          <!--<endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" contract="OurCompany.API.IOurService" />-->
          <!-- <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="OurCompany.API.IOurService" />-->
          <!--<endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="OurCompany.API.IOurService" />-->
          <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="OurCompany.API.IOurService" />
      </service>

    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Visual Studio look at the project**

(right click the image and choose to view in a new tab and you'll be able to see the jpeg clearly, at 100% size)
[image]

Comment: Did you set the .svc page as the start page?

Comment: Also, looking at your previous questions, if this is a RESTful service with no SOAP endpoints, then WCFTestClient won't work with it.  It only works with SOAP services.

Comment: what do you mean it's restful.  WSDL is soap.  If I am able to add a wsdl to another project then that means it's SOAP capable...not sure what you mean.  Sure, I decorated it with attributes like UriTemplate, WebGet, WebInvoke and such on my service methods but that doesn't stomp out SOAP and wsdl, you can still generate one unless I am not clear about what you are saying.

Comment: My comment was simply saying that **if** your WCF service is a RESTful service, with no SOAP endpoints available, you won't be able to use the WCFTestClient - though now I see you're talking about service host, not the test client.  If the service is exposed over a SOAP endpoint (like wsHttpBinding, for example), then yes, it should generate a WSDL.

Comment: what do you mean by no SOAP endopints, you mean endpoints in the config?  I have a mex endpoint in there for sure.

Comment: what's the diff, service host vs. test client?

Comment: Yeas it does generate a wsdl if I add the service reference to another C# project.  That's why I can't understand why the test client would not be showing anything after it said it added my service as well.

Comment: also I noticed also that I had created a "WCF Service Application" vs. "WCF Service Library".  Not sure which is what, but I assume I'm correct in creating it using the "WCF Service Application" project type?  We'll be hosting it in IIS for sure so I went with the first option.

Comment: I believe WCF Service Application is what you wanted, that's what I use as well.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make sure the solution is running in Debug mode (not release) and that the startup file is the **servicename.svc** file.  Take a look at [`Tips for Launching WCF Test Client`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx) for some more hints on your issue.

Can you share your contract definitions, as there might be an issue here with regard to a non-supported contract...if you take a look at [`this link`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/439be8da-4dde-4bd6-87c4-71c81aa6cfb2/this-operation-is-not-supported-in-wcf-test-client), you will see a post with the following list.

> The following is a list of features not supported by WCF Test Client:
>
> - Types: Stream, Message, XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlNode, types that
>   implement the IXmlSerializable interface, including the related
>   XmlSchemaProviderAttribute attribute, and the XDocument and XElement
>   types, the ADO.NET DataTable type and the DataSet type (as well as its
>   typed-derived classes).
> - Duplex contract.
> - Transaction.
> - Security: CardSpace , Certificate, and Username/Password.
> - Bindings:WSFederationbinding, any Context bindings and Https binding,
>   WebHttpbinding (Json response message support).

Comment: what is "transaction"

Comment: crap so we are using WebHttpBinding but also we're wanting to offer this as regular HTtpBinding for pox.  Check out my updated post in a few minutes, I'll post more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try highlighting (click on) the .svc file in your solution, then hit F5. That launches the WCF Test Client. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: when I do this, it takes me to my service url http://localhost:port/MyService.svc but does not open any WCF Test Client

Comment: and apart from this, I still don't understand why my WCF project properties and tabs look different than what's here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx so that I can add /client:WcfTestClient.exe which might make the test client finally come up?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I did not have my soap endpoint even enabled.  Duh.  You need an endpoint with binding type basicHttpBinding