# WCF Test Client says Added Service Successfully but shows nothing

Tags: wcf

I opened `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`

I added `http://localhost:44652/MyService.svc`

It says added successfully but I see absolutely nothing in the test client, it looks the same as if I first opened it.

Not sure why it would do that.  Here's my PC setup:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- VS 2012
- WCF 4
- I am using WebGet and WebInvoke for the REST portion but we want to also support wsdl

Comment: Are your methods also decorated with OperationContract?

Comment: yep http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485974/wcf-service-host-does-not-come-up-after-f5

Answer (score 4):

Web endpoints (aka REST) do not expose metadata that the WCF Test Client can understand.  There's a similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479187/wcf-rest-service-not-visible-in-wcftestclient).

Answer (score 2):

1) Please go to your browser and go to

```
http://localhost:44652/MyService.svc
```

You should see a web page that says "There is a service here."

2) Then you can use advanced rest service client by google chrome to test your service

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a version thing, but I got this to work in VS 2017 as follows:

1. Highlight the appropriate svc.cs for the REST service in Solution Explorer.
2. Start debugging (F5).

When WCF Test Client pops up, if you still don't see methods listed there, remove (temporarily) any REST `<service>` elements from web.config and then try again.  Reportedly, WCF Test Client does not work with the `webHttpBinding` that might be present in the `<service>` element.  Removal is not really a solution, but perhaps a good workaround for some scenarios where a quick test is needed.